# Bootstrap Autocomplete Input Dropdown not showing

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

This has stumped me for hours now. I am using Bootstrap 3 and trying to use the bootstrap autocomplete input with ajax ([docs here](https://bootstrap-autocomplete.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)). The data comes back from Ajax fine I can see that. The  dropdown also gets added to the DOM but it has the css property `display: none`. If I uncheck this in dev console I can see the dropdown but then it is stuck open.

Why is bootstrap not handling the open/close of the div?

Here is the code:

```js
<input class="form-control basicAutoComplete" placeholder="Select a ship" type="text" autocomplete="off">

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.basicAutoComplete').autoComplete({
            resolver: 'custom',
            formatResult: function (item) {
                return {
                    value: item.id,
                    text: "[" + item.id + "] " + item.name,
                };
            },
            events: {
                search: function (qry, callback) {
                    $.ajax(
                        "@Url.Action("shipdata", "autocomplete")",
                        {
                            dataType: "JSON", 
                            data: { 'qry': qry }
                        }
                    ).done(function (res) {
                        console.info(res.items);
                        callback(res.items);
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    });


</script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems that version 3 is broken, using the bootstrap version 4 worked.